# Is that possible to use the Ruby truck Library in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, .net, c#-3.0

I want to use the  Ruby truck Library in my c# application.
Is that possible to use that library to get the post parameters in a form or Html page.

Comment: Why not look at what is possible with the tool you have? If you do a C# application look at the C#/.Net tool set.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion .  i  worked in  ruby platform. i feel that im more comfortable with that Truck DLL. i want to use that DLL in C#.